# Change host app url before build Cordova Application in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: cordova, gulp, visual-studio-cordova, taco

I am using Visual Studio 2015 for develop a hosted web app using Apache Cordova by this tutorial http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/create-a-hosted-app
For open specific application url in Cordova WebView I should set this url in several places (config.xml, index.html, index.js). This url is different for develop and production environment. And before build application for production I should replace url in several places(config.xml, index.html, index.js). Is it possible to automate this task (maybe through gulp and taco-team-build module)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually my decision is quite simple.
I add both developer and production url to `config.xml` and to `index.html`

**config.xml**

```
<allow-navigation href="http://dev/*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://prod/*" />
```

**index.html**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: http://dev/ http://prod/ https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

And in **index.js** I create function which return necessary url.

```
function getConnectionInfo(production: boolean): ConnectionInfo
{
    if (production)
    {
        return {
            TargetUrl: 'http://prod/',
            UsePassword: false,
            User: '',
            Password: ''
        };
    }
        return {
        TargetUrl: 'http://dev/',
        UsePassword: false,
        User: '',
        Password: ''
    };
}
```

If I build production application I call `getConnectionInfo(true);`